# How to pass multiple parameters from robot script to python

Tags: python, robotframework

My requirement is to update a JSON structure and then write it into a file using key value pair. Below is my Python script, based upon the values for TESTVER, TESTLVL and TESTGRP we will receive from Robot script we need to update it:

```
cmd = 
"""{
        "TESTVER": "v1",
        "TESTLVL": "Level1",
        "TESTGRP": "SET"
}"""

class myLib(object):
    def change_test_details(self, ver, lvl, grp):
        d = json.loads(cmd)
        d["TESTVER"] = ver
        d["TESTLVL"] = lvl
        d["TESTGRP"] = grp
        print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

This is my Robot script extract:

```
test Suite to be selected and executed ${TEST}
    Log to Console   ${TEST}
    Change test details    "v1", "L1", "Get"
```

I keep getting "**No keyword with name 'Change test details' found.**" - how can I pass multiple param from Robot to Python scripts?

Comment: Is this literally your code? You're missing a colon at the end of the `def` line, and the body of the `def` isn't indented properly. You should be getting import errors on this file.

Comment: Thanks seems like type error - fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd = """{
        "TESTVER": "v1",
        "TESTLVL": "Level1",
        "TESTGRP": "SET"
}"""

class myLib(object):
    def change_test_details(self, ver, lvl, grp,filename):
        d = json.loads(cmd)
        d["TESTVER"] = ver
        d["TESTLVL"] = lvl
        d["TESTGRP"] = grp
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(d, outfile,indent=2)
        return 'Done'
x=myLib()
ver=1
lvl=1
grp=1
filename =r'file.json'
v=x.change_test_details(ver, lvl, grp,filename)
print(v)
"""
output

done
"""
```

Comment: But I need to call it from Robot script?

Comment: is robot script python or bash? to run this script you can do cmd line argument ( robot data) to pass the values to this script and save the dumps

Comment: Thanks - the issue turned out that we cannot make use of print in python script when called from robot

Comment: you can use log `import logging' to check what you got and see it in debug mode or in log file